# Encode/Decode enum for Swift (Xcode 6.1)

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have

```
var priority : Priority! = Priority.defaultPriority

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeInteger(priority.toRaw(), forKey: "priority") //toRaw may not yield the result I am expecting
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        priority = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("priority") //complaining about conflicting types
    }
```

with the enum being the following:

```
enum Priority : Int {
        case defaultPriority = 0
        case lowPriority = 1
        case mediumPriority = 2
        case highPriority = 3
    }
```

What is the best way to encode/decode this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Priority.init(rawValue:)` should work.

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeInteger(priority.rawValue, forKey: "priority")
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    priority = Priority(rawValue: aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("priority"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the update for 6.1.