# Sharing UserDefaults between extensions

Tags: swift, ios-app-extension, today-extension, userdefaults, ios-app-group

Creating a Today widget and I am using `UserDefaults(suiteName:)` to persist some data. In the main application I am using `UserDefaults.standard()`. This can't be read (or can it?) by the extension which is why I use the `suiteName:` constructor.

Data that user persist to `UserDefaults.standard()` in the main app needs to be available in the extension.

At this time I am persisting to both so that the values can be shared

```
 UserDefaults.standard().set:...forKey:...
 UserDefaults(suiteName:...)().set:...forKey:...
 ...
```

Question is should I drop `UserDefaults.standard()` all together and just use `UserDefaults(suiteName:)` in my application, or is this bad practice and if so why?

Edit: I am using an App group container. For clarification I am asking should I just replace `standard()` with `suiteName:`  throughout my project?

Comment: if you want to share resources between the extension and the app, the best way is to create an _App Group_ and use the shared `UserDefault` (by `-suiteName:`) or the default `FileManager` (by `-forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:`) only – you may not need the standard user-defaults or file-manager any longer (but if you need to be sure you want isolate data from the extension, you still can use those sandboxes).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You cannot use `UserDefaults.standard` to share data between a host app and its app extension. You instead have to create a shared container with `UserDefaults(suiteName:)` to share data.

> Even though an app extension bundle is nested within its containing
>   app’s bundle, the running app extension and containing app have no
>   direct access to each other’s containers.
>
> To enable data sharing, use Xcode or the Developer portal to enable
>   app groups for the containing app and its contained app extensions.
>   Next, register the app group in the portal and specify the app group
>   to use in the containing app.
>
> After you enable app groups, an app extension and its containing app
>   can both use the NSUserDefaults API to share access to user
>   preferences. To enable this sharing, use the initWithSuiteName: method
>   to instantiate a new NSUserDefaults object, passing in the identifier
>   of the shared group.

For more, refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

How to use App Groups: https://github.com/pgpt10/Today-Widget

**Standard or SuiteName?**

Use standard one for data that is only for Host App. Use suiteName for data that you want to share between Extension and Host App. Just don't persist the same data in both of them. Avoid data redundancy. Use both of them according to the context.

Comment: Apologies I assumed that as I was using ‘initSuiteName:’ that it would already give the impression I was using an App group. Which I am. Updated OQ to clarify this. Thanks

Comment: So what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I’m current persisting same data to both standard & suiteName constructors. Should I just drop standard() and use suiteName.

Comment: Use standard one for data that is only for Host App. Use suiteName for data that you want to share between Extension and Host App. Just don't persist the same data in both of them. Avoid data redundancy. Use both of them according to the context.

Comment: (shouldn't the references to "host app" in this answer actually refer to the "container app"?)

Comment: I've successful implement your solution, however, if I need to make app do things base at extension's lifecycle.
Say call chatGPT api when the custom keyboard extension is at viewWillAppear, and de-init the service when keyboard is at viewWillDiappear, how to approach such things?

Answer (score 82):

Make sure `App Groups` is enabled for **ALL OF YOUR TARGETS** (your app and extensions targets) in the *Capabilities* tab

[image]

And then use the **group's identifier** above as suite name when create `UserDefaults`:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.YourCompany.YourApp")
```

Comment: This step is HIGHLY important.

Comment: Can we add any name to the group's identifier?

Comment: Thanks Tai Le. I was stuck on this.
@user4150758 We have to set suiteName same as the App Groups name. otherwise it wan't work

Answer (score 48):

A simple example where I create a shared bundle:

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.your.bundle.here") {
    userDefaults.set("test 1" as AnyObject, forKey: "key1")
    userDefaults.set("test 2" as AnyObject, forKey: "key2")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

This is how you can read it later:

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.your.bundle.here") {
    let value1 = userDefaults.string(forKey: "key1")
    let value2 = userDefaults.string(forKey: "key2")
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `synchroniz`

Comment: This does not actually answer the question which one to use. If you do what you have written wont work if data was saved from host application using UserDefaults.standard().

Answer (score 14):

Also make sure you add App Groups to the correct Configuration (Debug, Release). If you add App Groups in Debug for your application target and try to use it in Release config for your extension, then it wont work.

If you add in Debug config (for app target), then use it in debug config (for extension target)

Comment: It was so simple and i waste an hour. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Meh I wish I had read this post before wasting 3 hours... I had my extension group only on profile...

Comment: @Rahul Chhetri Not sure I see where this would be added to a Debug only configuration. I don't see where App Groups can be assigned to a configuration. Please clarify

Comment: @JeffB6688 Okay I was confused by this initially. But as I was typing my original thoughts I discovered this. If you click on your project where the General, Signing & capabilities etc are. Select Signing & Capabilities, underneath that, there is "All, Debug, Release". This is what Rahul means by 'adding the app group to the debug and release'

Comment: Capabilities and Entitlements are sometimes managed by Xcode differently between `debug` and `release`, so this has probably happened to a lot of us.

Answer (score 1):

PGDev: augmentation:

you can't avoid redundancy when dragging Settings (preferences) https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html to an extension:
they are contained in the app private bundle and have to be replicated
into suitenamed bundle to become available to an app extension

Answer (score 1):

Wasted a lot of time, and the problem was in adding of app groups only for release configuration, and of course while testing of debug configuration - I couldn't access to shared data between app extension and container app. So, be sure u adding app groups to both configurations - release and debug.

[image]