# Why would I put data in the app's documents folder instead of the group container?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios-extensions, ios-app-group

My iOS app is going to have an extension. I'm planning to share the documents & database with the extension by creating an app group and putting the files into the group's container, per the official guidelines.

Are there any downsides to keeping all of the app's data in the group container?

Is there a reason to leave any data in the app's folder instead of the group folder, seeing as it might be used or written by the extension in the future?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607903/sharing-userdefaults-between-extensions