# UserDefaults in Call Directory Extension's Caller ID

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callkit, caller-id

This is the story:

In main app:
  - Some numbers are fetched from my web-service. These numbers append to NSUserDefaults.

In Call directory Extension:

- Retrieving from UserDefaults:

  ```
  private func retrievePhoneNumbersToIdentifyAndLabels() -> (phoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber], labels: [String]) {

      let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: GROUP_NAME)

      let phones = defaults?.array(forKey: "phoneArray") as! [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber]
      let names = defaults?.array(forKey: "nameArray") as! [String]

      return (phones,names)
      } }
  ```

And here is the Call Directory Extension's function:

```
private func addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {

    let (phoneNumbers, labels) = retrievePhoneNumbersToIdentifyAndLabels()

       print(phoneNumbers)
       print(labels)

    for (phoneNumber, label) in zip(phoneNumbers, labels) {
        context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber, label: label)
    }
}
```

Problem: When I am trying to enable Call Blocking & Identification in Setting on my device, it gives "Error Enabling Extension" error. And also, in debugger of Xcode,

> [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x10fe251d0> (Domain: GROUP_NAME, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd

But here is the interesting parts of the story:

After these problems, somehow, print functions which in above function are running correctly. **I mean, it can save phone numbers and labels to UserDefaults and also it can read from UserDefaults. To be clarify, I can reach UserDefaults in my extension.** There is no problem.

Note: **Of course, app groups of both main app and Call Directory Extension have been set** and phone numbers have correct typealias which is Int64. And also, phone numbers are sorted ascending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing UserDefaults between extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607903/sharing-userdefaults-between-extensions)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I would expect you to read better what I wrote.  @TomE

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't accidentally corrupt the data. Sharing data files means there might be more than one process trying to use a file at the same time. Sandboxing on iOS means this is a somewhat rare situation, but that doesn't mean it's OK to ignore it. You may need to use "NSFileCoordinator"

you can find more explanatory information in this address : [enter link description here](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You must test it in Ad-Hoc or Release mode!
It seems that in Debug mode it doesn't work sometime!