# Saving a Codable Struct to UserDefaults with Swift

Tags: swift, codable, userdefaults

I am trying to encode a struct

```
struct Configuration : Encodable, Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case contents = "contents"
    }
    var title : String?
    var contents: [[Int]]?
}
```

into JSON to store in a local key of UserDefaults.standard. I have the following code:

```
let jsonString = Configuration(title: nameField.text, contents: newContents)
let info = ["row" as String: jsonString as Configuration]
print("jsonString = \(jsonString)")
//trying to save object
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let recode = try! JSONEncoder().encode(jsonString)
defaults.set(recode, forKey: "simulationConfiguration")
//end of saving local
```

The print returns:

```
jsonString = Configuration(title: Optional("config"), contents: Optional([[4, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5]]))
```

so I believe I am creating the object correctly. However, when I try and retrieve the key the next time I run the simulator I get nothing.
I put the following in AppDelegate and it always returns No Config.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let config = defaults.string(forKey: "simulationConfiguration") ?? "No Config"
        print("from app delegate = \(config.description)")
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: May be someone will find this `UserDefaultEncoded` helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58696740/1746142 It allows to save any `Codable` struct to UserDefaults.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you are saving a `Data` value (which is correct)

```
defaults.set(recode, forKey: "simulationConfiguration")
```

But here you are reading a `String`

```
defaults.string(forKey: "simulationConfiguration")
```

You cannot save `Data`, read `String` and expect it to work.

### Let's fix your code

First of all you don't need to manually specify the Coding Keys. So your struct become simply this

```
struct Configuration : Codable {
    var title : String?
    var contents: [[Int]]?
}
```

### Saving

Now here's the code for saving it

```
let configuration = Configuration(title: "test title", contents: [[1, 2, 3]])
if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(configuration) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "simulationConfiguration")
}
```

### Loading

And here's the code for reading it

```
if
    let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "simulationConfiguration") as? Data,
    let configuration = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Configuration.self, from: data) {
    print(configuration)
}
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`encode(_:)` function of `JSONEncoder` returns `Data`, not `String`. This means when you need to get the `Configuration` back from `UserDefaults` you need to get data and decode them.
Here is example:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
guard let configData = defaults.data(forKey: "simulationConfiguration") else {
  return nil // here put something or change the control flow to if statement
}
return try? JSONDecoder().decode(Configuration.self, from: configData)
```

---

- you also don't need to assign value to all the cases in `CodingKeys`, the values is automatically the name of the case
- if you are conforming to both, `Encodable` and `Decodable`, you can simply use `Codable` instead as it is combination of both and defined as `typealias Codable = Encodable & Decodable`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an external dependency that saves a boat load of frustration, checkout [SwifterSwift](http://swifterswift.com/docs/Extensions/UserDefaults.html)

Here's how I did it in two lines using their UserDefaults extension.

For setting:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(object: configuration, forKey: "configuration")
```

For retrieving the object:

```
guard let configuration = UserDefaults.standard.object(Configuration.self, with: "configuration") else { return }
print(configuration)
```

That's about it..!!

Comment: And you should only have to implement Configuration : Codable on your class.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your UserDefault stored property will be look something like this,

```
private let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

var configuration: Configuration? {
    get {
        do {
            let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: "configuration_key")
            if let data {
                let config = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                return config
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Preference \(#function) json decode error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return nil
    } set {
        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
            userDefaults.set(data, forKey: "configuration_key")
        } catch let error {
            print("Preference \(#function) json encode error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```