# UserDefaults array is coming back empty

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

Im trying to set an array of objects to user defaults but is not appending.

declaring the var for the array
   in my AllFormulas Class:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard    
static var lineOne1 = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "line1") as? [Formulas] ?? []
init() {
//formula names and values
```

then im starting with an empty array

```
lineOne1 = []
}
```

appending to the array
   in my AddViewController Class :

```
 func lineOneAdd() {
    let line1 = lineOne1
    lineOne1.append(formulaAppend)
    defaults.set(line1, forKey: "line1")
    defaults.synchronize()

}
```

then calling the userDefaults in view did load in 
  MainViewController Class:

```
line1[indexPath.row] // as my cellForRowAt in tableView


print(line1)
//which prints : []
```

any idea what im doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: And the call to `synchronize` is obsolete. It should be removed.

Comment: Are the userDefaults global? when im calling on forKey: "line1" , my lineOne1 variable is declared in another class. would that matter?

Comment: yeah, sorry.. Im just trying to simplify it for ease. I didn't specify, thats on me

Comment: I updated my question to show classes

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be appending to the wrong array:

```
lineOne1.append(formulaAppend)
```

Should be:

```
line1.append(formulaAppend)
```

Comment: I tried that. but this is what happens when i call that function "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "MyProject.Formulas"
) for key line1'

Comment: @MarkRogers does your `Formula` class implement (subclass) `Codable`? Also rmaddy is correct, you should be modifying the global.

Comment: No, Formula does not have a subclass. I have another file AllFormulas class which then I use init() to declare each formulas values... Its in that class I am also declaring my arrays for lineOne1. Then in a AddViewController I select the formula I would like to append and view on my MainViewController in a tableView.

Comment: If you need to store an object in UserDefaults, I think conforming to `Codable` is best practice. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876420/save-struct-to-userdefaults). Please note though you typically should use CoreData to store objects as opposed to UserDefaults, which is more often used for preferences.

Comment: I did go the route of CoreData first but was having issues with formula I have showing in the tableview. I starting thinking UserDefaults might be an easier approach to the solution