# UserDefaults Swift

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I have question regarding UserDefaults.

Is it possible to store several fields in userdefaults?  I am gonna show a sample example below code

```
fistname = UserDefaults.standard.set(name,forKey: "namekey")
fistnameone = UserDefaults.standard.set(nameone,forKey: "nameonekey")
fistnametwo = UserDefaults.standard.set(nametwo,forKey: "nametwokey")
```

can I do store many values or userDefaults are supposed to be used for only storing one value?

Comment: Have you tried running that code and then retrieving the data, to see if it works?

Comment: Actually, in one controller, I have used one value in UserDefaults which was successful. But later if I use again they are giving nil

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can store many key values data in userDefaults.
The documents https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults said it clearly.

```
UserDefaults
An interface to the user’s defaults database, where you store key-value pairs persistently across launches of your app.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary for all the values you want to store in `UserDefaults`. If you want to store structure objects to be saved then please follow below link :

[Save Struct to UserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876420/save-struct-to-userdefaults)

Hope this helps you in some way.