# Problem saving checkmark to tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, persistence

I am having issues saving a check mark to my table view, essentially it is a fitness app and when the user selects a workout a table view presents it, when an exercise is pressed a check mark presents, but I am unable to save that check mark to its desired exercise. 
Below I have given one of the workouts as an example and the tableView controller.

I have posted this previously but not yet had any responses that worked so any help would be much appreciated.

example of one of the workouts :

```
import Foundation

class The600Workout {


    let workoutArray = [

                        "Don't forget to warm up before every workout!",
                        "Start with little/ no weight and work your way up",
                        "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
                        "Pull ups | 25 Reps",
                        "Lunges | 50 Reps (Low weight)",
                        "Calf Raises | 50 Reps (Low weight)",
                        "Shoulder press | 50 Reps (Low weight)",
                        "Push ups | 50 Reps",
                        "Shrugs | 50 Reps (Low weight)",
                        "Leg raises | 50 Reps",
                        "Bench press | 50 Reps (Low weight)",
                        "More Pull ups | 25 Reps",
                        "Squats | 50 Reps (Low weight)",
                        "Incline Bench press | 50 Reps (Low weight)",
                        "Bicep curls | 50 Reps (Low weight)",
                        "Tricep pull downs | 50 Reps (Low weight)"]
}
```

tableView Controller:

```
import UIKit

class workoutTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutTableView: UITableView!

    var navTitle: String = ""
    var workout = [String]()
    let tlabel = UILabel()
    var completed: [Bool] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setWorkout()
        workoutTableView.delegate = self
        workoutTableView.dataSource = self
        tlabel.text = navTitle
        tlabel.textAlignment = .center
        tlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 30)
        tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        navigationItem.titleView = tlabel
        completed = [Bool](repeating: false, count: workout.count)
    }

    func setWorkout() {

        if navTitle == "The 600 Workout" {

            workout = The600Workout().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "5 Days for Muscle" {

          workout = FiveDaysForMuscle().workoutArray

        }

        else if navTitle == "Marathon Ready" {

          workout = MarathonReady().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "HIIT @ Home" {

          workout = HIITAtHome().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Get Strong" {

          workout = GetStrong().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Body Weight Blast" {

          workout = BodyWeightBlast().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Bands Pump" {

          workout = BandsPump().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Quickie Warm up" {

          workout = QuickieWarmUp().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "The Best Circuit Workout" {

          workout = TheBestCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "The Gym HIIT Workout" {

          workout = GymHIIT().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "The Ultimate Workout" {

          workout = UltimateWorkout().workoutArray
        }


         else if navTitle == "Warm up For Weights" {

            workout = WarmUpForWeights().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "6 Day Bro Split" {

          workout = SixDayBroSplit().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Explosive Workout" {

         workout = ExplosiveWorkout().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Strength Circuit" {

          workout = StrengthCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Killer Circuit" {

          workout = KillerCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Fitness Test" {

          workout = FitnessTest().workoutArray
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workout.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        completed[indexPath.row] = !completed[indexPath.row]
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = completed[indexPath.row] ?  .checkmark : .none
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = workout[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = completed[indexPath.row] ?  .checkmark : .none
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3285208941, blue: 0.5748849511, alpha: 1)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your workout model appears to be an array of strings. You will need your model to be an array of struct that has, say, a string and a Boolean so that you can track the checked state of each item.

Comment: Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59605872/swift-tableview-checkmark-repeating-on-scroll/59606366#59606366

Comment: I have implemented this but that doesn't resolve the need to save it. Saving is fine but loading the current state is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    completed[indexPath.row] = !completed[indexPath.row]
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
}
```

And also add:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    completed[indexPath.row] = !completed[indexPath.row]
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
}
```