# iOS Swift - reading a persisted data model after having altered properties in that model

Tags: swift, xcode, types, persistence, decoder

Thanks in advance for your help.

I want to persist data such as a user's stats. Let's say I have a data model, a class 'Stats' with a few properties, and it gets saved to the user's device. Supposing that I've released the app, users are recording their stats but then later on I want to make changes to the class - more or fewer properties, maybe even renaming them (etc.), ahead of a new build release. But after these changes have been made, the type 'Stats' is now different to the one the users have saved on their device, so it won't be able to decode and it seems like all the user's previous data up until that point would be lost/unattainable.

How can I add make these kinds of changes to the class in a way in which the PropertyListDecoder will still be able to decode the stats that are still on the user's device?

This is basically what I have:

```
class Stat: Codable  {

    let questionCategory = questionCategory()

    var timesAnsweredCorrectly: Int = 0
    var timesAnsweredFirstTime: Int = 0
    var timesFailed: Int = 0

    static func saveToFile(stats: [Stat]) {

        let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        let encodedSettings = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(stats)
        try? encodedSettings?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)
    }

    static func loadFromFile() -> [Stat]? {
        let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        if let retrievedSettingsData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL), let decodedSettings = try? propertyListDecoder.decode([Stat].self, from: retrievedSettingsData) {

            return decodedSettings
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

static let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

static let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("savedVerbStats").appendingPathExtension("plist")
```

It seems that even just adding a new property to 'Stat' will cause the user's previous persisted data to become un-decodable as type 'Stat', and loadFromFile() will return nil.

Any advice would be great! I'm sure I'm going about this the wrong way. I figured that the array [Stat] would be too big to persist in UserDefaults but even then I think this problem would still exist... Can't find anything about it online; it seems that once you've got your users using a persisted class you can't then alter it. I tried using default values for the new properties but the result is the same.

The only solution I can think of is breaking down the class into literals and saving all *these* in some kind of a tuple/dictionary form instead. Then I would decode that raw data, and have a function to assemble and create the class out of whatever relevant data can still be taken from the old version of the 'Stat' type. Seems like a big workaround and I'm sure you guys know a much a better way.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Removing* a property is easy enough. Just delete its definition from the Stat class and existing data for that property will be deleted when you read and save stats again.

The key to *adding* new properties is to make them optional. For example:

```
var newProperty: Int?
```

When a previously existing stat is decoded the first time, this property will be nil, but all the other properties will be set correctly. You can set and save the new property as needed.

It may be a minor inconvenience to have all new properties as optional, but it opens the door to other possible migration schemes without losing data.

EDIT: Here is a more complicated migration scheme that avoids optionals for new properties.

```
class Stat: Codable {
    var timesAnsweredCorrectly: Int = 0
    var timesAnsweredFirstTime: Int = 0
    var timesFailed: Int = 0

    //save all stats in the new Stat2 format
    static func saveToFile(stats: [Stat2]) {
        let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        let encodedSettings = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(stats)
        try? encodedSettings?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)
    }

    //return all stats in the new Stat2 format
    static func loadFromFile() -> [Stat2]? {
        let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        //first, try to decode existing stats as Stat2
        if let retrievedSettingsData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL), let decodedSettings = try? propertyListDecoder.decode([Stat2].self, from: retrievedSettingsData) {

            return decodedSettings
        } else if let retrievedSettingsData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL), let decodedSettings = try? propertyListDecoder.decode([Stat].self, from: retrievedSettingsData) {
            //since we couldn't decode as Stat2, we decoded as Stat

            //convert existing Stat instances to Stat2, giving the newProperty an initial value
            var newStats = [Stat2]()
            for stat in decodedSettings {
                let newStat = Stat2()
                newStat.timesAnsweredCorrectly = stat.timesAnsweredCorrectly
                newStat.timesAnsweredFirstTime = stat.timesAnsweredFirstTime
                newStat.timesFailed = stat.timesFailed
                newStat.newProperty = 0
                newStats.append(newStat)
            }
            return newStats
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    static let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    static let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("savedVerbStats").appendingPathExtension("plist")
}

class Stat2: Stat {
    var newProperty: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, wasn't sure if I'd missed something. My approach followed Apple's own guidelines to the letter but they don't mention anything about accounting for whether the encoded type gets altered between builds - which seems like a pretty important consideration for data persistence. Will have a play around with the optional properties and your migration scheme idea.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Mike's response, I came up with a migration scheme that seems to solve the issue of the optionals and doesn't require any new classes every time the data model is altered. Part of the issue is that a developer may change or add properties to a class that gets persisted and Xcode would never flag this as an issue, which may result in your user's app trying to read the previous data class saved to the device, returning nil and in all likelihood overwriting all the data in question with a reformatted model.

---

Instead of writing the class (e.g. Stat) to the disk (which is what Apple suggests in its teaching resources), I save a new struct "StatData" which comprises only optional properties of the data that I want to write to the file:

```
struct StatData: Codable {

    let key: String
    let timesAnsweredCorrectly: Int?
    let timesAnsweredFirstTime: Int?
    let timesFailed: Int?
}
```

That way I can read the properties from the file and any added or deleted properties from the struct would just return nil instead of making the entire struct unreadable. Then I have two functions to convert 'StatData' into 'Stat' (and back), providing default values in case any have been returned nil.

```
    static func convertToData(_ stats: [Stat]) -> [StatData] {

        var data = [StatData]()
        for stat in stats {
            let dataItem = StatData(key: stat.key, timesAnsweredCorrectly: stat.timesAnsweredCorrectly, timesAnsweredFirstTime: stat.timesAnsweredFirstTime, timesFailed: stat.timesFailed)
            data.append(dataItem)
        }
        return data
    }

    static func convertFromData(_ statsData: [StatData]) -> [Stat] {

        // if any of these properties weren't previously saved to the device, they will return the default values but the rest of the data will remain accessible.
        var stats = [Stat]()
        for item in statsData {
            let stat = stat.init(key: item.key, timesAnsweredCorrectly: item.timesAnsweredCorrectly ?? 0, timesAnsweredFirstTime: item.timesAnsweredFirstTime ?? 0, timesFailed: item.timesFailed ?? 0)
            stats.append(stat)
        }
        return stats
    }
```

I then call these functions when reading or saving the data to disk. The advantage of this is that I can choose which properties from the Stat class that I want to save, and because the StatData model is a struct, the memberwise initializer will warn any developer who changes the data model that they will also need to account for the change when reading old data from the file.

This seems to do the job. Any comments or other suggestions would be appreciated