# Issue with UserDefaults (converting data to array and back)

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, unrecognized-selector, nskeyedarchiver

**What I want to do:**

I want to get an array from UserDefaults that I saved beforehand and append a custom object to it. Afterwards I want to encode it as a Data-type again and set this as the UserDefaults Key again.

**My problem:**

The encoding part is what is not working as intended for me.
It says: `-[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000011a540`

But I do not know how to fix this.

Below is my code for more context:

```
do {

let decoded  = defaults.object(forKey: "ExArray") as! Data
var exo = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(decoded) as! [Exerc]
exo.append(datas[indexPath.row])

let enco = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: exo, requiringSecureCoding: false)   <- Here is the error
defaults.set(enco, forKey: "ExArray")

} catch {

print("Error encoding custom object NOSEARCHO")

}
```

This is how Exerc looks:

```
struct Exerc: Codable {
    var title: String
    var exID: String
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, I suggest you use `Codable` to convert your array/data in both directions. See [Save Struct to UserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876420/save-struct-to-userdefaults)

Comment: By the sounds of the error, you just need to implement the `NSCoding` protocol on your `Exerc` class: https://www.raywenderlich.com/6733-nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-permanently-save-app-data. I second the `Codable` option if you want to use a more modern API.

Comment: @Kubee added now ```struct: Codable {...}```, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Codable uses JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder.  You will have to encode and decode your data using those classes and scrap NSKeyedUnarchiver/NSKeyedArchiver

Comment: Impossible to reply without knowing what an Exerc is.

Comment: So you cannot use Exerc with NSKeyedUnarchiver etc., because it is not compliant with NSCoding. Either that or, as you've been told, scrap NSKeyedUnarchiver and use Codable instead. Pick one.

Comment: I try to do it with Codable now. Any help or direction would be cool! @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are not using the archiver features, so why don't you just use the codable?

```
do {
    
    let key = "ExArray"
    let decoded = defaults.data(forKey: key)!
    var exo = try JSONDecoder().decode([Exerc].self, from: decoded)
    exo.append(datas[indexPath.row])

    let enco = try JSONEncoder().encode(exo)
    defaults.set(enco, forKey: key)

} catch {
    print("Error encoding/decoding custom object NOSEARCHO", error)
}
```

<sub>It just a simple refactored MVP of the original code, but you can even work a bit on this and make it human readable right in the `plist` file!</sub>

Comment: Solved it myself in the mean time and it looks like your answer. Have to wait 23hrs to give you the bounty. But anyway, thank you.