# Combine these into a single var

Tags: swift

Apologies for the stupid question, I'm still really new to the Swift language.

Following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45909055/13502835) by @matt, I want to combine these two statements into a single var

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(songs), forKey:"songs")
```

```swift
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"songs") as? Data {
    let songs2 = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<Song>.self, from: data)
}
```

I've thought maybe using a var with `didSet {}` like something along the lines of

```swift
var test: Array = UserDefaults.standard. { // ??
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(test), forKey: "songs")
    }
}
```

But I can't think of where to go from here.
Thanks for the help in advance :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property should not be a stored property. It should be a computed property, with `get` and `set` accessors:

```
var songsFromUserDefaults: [Song]? {
    get {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"songs") as? Data {
            return try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<Song>.self, from: data)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    set {
        if let val = newValue {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(val), forKey:"songs")
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that since the decoding can fail, the getter returns an optional. This forces the setter to accept an optional `newValue`, and I have decided to only update UserDefaults when the value is not nil. Another design is to use `try!` when decoding, or return an empty array when the decoding fails. This way the type of the property can be non-optional, and the nil-check in the setter can be removed.

Comment: `Missing return in a function expected to return '[Song]?'` in the get section

Answer (score 2):

While you can use computed properties like [Sweeper suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64951392/1271826) (+1), I might consider putting this logic in a property wrapper.

In SwiftUI you can use [`AppStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage). Or you can roll your own. Here is a simplified example:

```
@propertyWrapper public struct Saved<Value: Codable> {
    private let key: String

    public var wrappedValue: Value? {
        get {
            guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key) else { return nil }
            return (try? JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data))
        }

        set {
            guard
                let value = newValue,
                let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value)
            else {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
                return
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    init(key: String) {
        self.key = key
    }
}
```

And then you can do things like:

```
@Saved(key: "username") var username: String?
```

Or

```
@Saved(key: "songs") var songs: [Song]?
```