# Swift enum and NSCoding

Tags: swift, enums, nscoding

I have a 'Thing' object with a String property and an NSImage property; the Thing class has encodeWithCoder: and decodeWithCoder: methods, and I can archive and unarchive a [Thing] array using NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver.

So far, so good. Now I want to expand my Thing class by an array of directions, where 'Direction' is the following enum:

```
enum Direction{

case North(direction:String)
case East(direction:String)
case South(direction:String)
case West(direction:String)

}
```

In other words, the data I wish to store is

```
thing1.directions: Direction = [.North("thing2"), .South("thing3")]
```

(In a more perfect world, I'd be using direct references to my Things rather than just their names, but I realise that this will easily create reference cycles - can't set a reference to another Thing until that Thing has been created - so I'll refrain. I'm looking for a quick and dirty method to save my app data and move on.)

Since I will be needing directions elsewhere, this is a separate entity, not just an enum inside the Thing class. (Not sure whether that makes a difference.)

What is the best way to make my Direction enum conform to NSCoding? 
The best workaround I can come up with involves creating a [String: String] dictionary with "North" and "South" as keys and "thing2" and "thing3" as values, and reconstruct my enum property from that, but is there a better way? 
And for that matter, is there a way to make tuples conform to NSCoding because right now (String, String) gets me a 'not compatible to protocol "AnyObject"' error.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What I do is give the enum a type and encode and decode its raw value, or else implement `description` for the enum and encode and decode that string. Either way (or if you use some other way), you obviously need a way to convert in both directions between an enumerator and an archivable type.

Comment: how do you encode / decode `description`? For instance, the following throws an initialization error: `Direction(description: (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("direction") as! String)) ?? .North`

Comment: @Anconia Ask it as a question, not as a comment, please! There's no room to talk about it here... :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's time I buy your book(s) :-)

Comment: @Anconia and in fact it covers this situation: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_enum_initializers

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to access the enum from the RAW value.  Full example and discussion here:

[How do I encode enum using NSCoder in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift)

Note this change in Xcode 6.1 " move code from the old-style “fromRaw()/toRaw()” enum APIs to the new style-initializer and “rawValue” property"

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html