# How do I encode Character using NSCoder in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

**Like**

[How do I encode enum using NSCoder in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift)

**Code**:

```
import Foundation

class Car: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var bmw: Character
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        bmw = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("bmw") as? Character)!
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
        encoder.encodeObject(bmw, forKey: "bmw")
    }
}
```

Xcode throw an **error**:

Cannot invoke 'encodeObject' with an argument list of type '(Characher, forKey: String)'

What should I do with Character in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error is that, while `String` is subtype of `AnyObject`, `Character` is not (since a character is not an object). A way to solve your problem could be the following:

```
class Car: NSObject {
  var bmw: Character
  required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    bmw = Character(decoder.decodeObjectForKey("bmw") as! String)
  }

  func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
    encoder.encodeObject(String(bmw), forKey: "bmw")
  }
}
```

Here you convert the character to a string before encoding it, and convert back to character after decoding.

Comment: Thank you! And I want to know `Character(abc)` and `String(abc)` wether cost a lot system resources. Beacuse I will have thousands of objects to deal with.

Comment: I don't think these operations will cost too much, since they can be efficiently executed in O(1) time.

Comment: And do you know other method to solve it without convert between character and string?

Comment: Maybe you could change the representation of characters and use an Int instead, using `encodeInt:forKey` and `decodeIntForKey`, and then converting the integer to a character only when you need to print it?

Comment: Thanks. I need a Character to be a key in my class, and all of characters are Chinese utf-8 characters. :-(