# How do I encode [Character : Int] property using NSCoder in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, nscoding

```
import UIKit

class Foo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var cx: [Character : Int]

    init(cx: [Character : Int]) {
        self.cx = cx
    }

    // MARK: - <NSCoding>

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let cx = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "cxKey") as! [Character : Int]
        self.init(cx: cx)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(cx, forKey: "cxKey")
    }
}
```

calling:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var foo = Foo(cx: ["C": 5, "X": 6])

        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: foo)
        print("encodedData: \(encodedData))")

        if let foo1 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedData) as? Foo {
            print("cx = ", foo1.cx)
        } else{
            print("There is an issue")
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode throws an error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: sorry, added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason**

That is because the `Character`-typed keys in `cx` will be boxed as `_SwiftValue` objects which will be sent `encodeWithCoder:` which leads to the unrecognized selector exception.

See the comment at the top of [SwiftValue.h](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftValue.h):

> This implements the Objective-C class that is used to carry Swift
>   values that have been bridged to Objective-C objects without special
>   handling. The class is opaque to user code, but is `NSObject`- and
>   `NSCopying`- conforming and is understood by the Swift runtime for
>   dynamic casting back to the contained type.

**Solution**

If you can change the type of `cx` to `[String : Int]`, everything will work out of the box (no pun intended).

Otherwise you will have to convert `cx` in `Foo.encode(with:)` to something that can be encoded (like `[String : Int]`, for instance) and vice versa in the decoding initializer.

See [How do I encode Character using NSCoder in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240450/how-do-i-encode-character-using-nscoder-in-swift) and [How do I encode enum using NSCoder in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift) for some code.