# Encode enum with NSCoding

Tags: swift, nscoding, nscoder

I am implementing NSCoding in my library, but I need to serialize an enum variable and I can't pass it in for the function that takes `AnyObject?`. How would this be done in Swift? Here is my enum:

```
enum ServerType {
  case PC
  case PE
}
```

Also, `toRaw()` and `fromRaw()` do not exist for `ServerType`. The only property I can access is `hashValue`, and there are no methods I can access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I encode enum using NSCoder in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift)

Comment: Try to encode NSNumber(unsignedShort: enumvalue)

Comment: @Teddy I get the error: "Argument labels '(CUnsignedShort:)' do not match any available overloads"

Comment: enumvalue.rawvalue

Comment: @Teddy Nope. Only `hashValue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to @Bennett's answer, but it you can use it with `NSNumber` as shown:

```swift
enum ServerType: UInt {
    case PC
    case PE
}

let someType: ServerType = .PE
NSNumber(value: someType.rawValue) // 1
```

Comment: Would also work, but I just noticed that for my code there is a case where it should be string.

Comment: Yes, but I also included this because it has some advantages. Your solution allows for reordering but not renaming the cases, but mine allows for renaming but not reordering the cases which I think is more useful. You can use either answer, just be sure to mark one of them as correct if it works.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm changing a path like `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com/pc` or `https://example.com/pe` depending on the value. If it's a string, I can just say `case PC = "pc"` and `case PE = "pe"` and then use `https://example.com/\(serverValue.rawValue)"`. In an ambiguous case, this would work and have advantages.

Comment: @Bennett You still can. Just do: `"https://example.com/\(someType)"` or, in your case, `"https://example.com/\(serverValue)"`

Comment: But then it would be `https://example.com/1` (if `serverValue = .PE`) instead of `https://example.com/pe`

Comment: @Bennett Strange, both of these worked just fine in my testing: `let url = "https://example.com/\(someType)"` or `let url = "https://example.com/\(ServerType.PE)"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131420/discussion-between-bennett-and-coder256).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
enum ServerType : String {
  case PC
  case PE
}
```

and you should be able to use the `rawValue` parameter.