# How can I encode (with NSCoding) an enum that has no rawValue?

Tags: swift, encoding, enums, swift3, nscoding

I'm trying to make my class conform to `NSCoding`, but running into problems because one of its properties is an enum, like this:

```
enum Direction {
    case north
    case south
}
```

If enums were codable I could do it like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var direction: Direction!
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        direction = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "direction") as! Direction
    }
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(direction, forKey: "direction")
    }
}
```

but enums aren't codable so `encode()` throws an error.

The answers to "[How do I encode enum using NSCoder in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift)" suggest encoding the enum's `rawValue` and then initializing it from `rawValue` on the other end. But in this case, `Direction` doesn't have a `rawValue`!

It does have a `hashValue`, which seems promising. I can encode its `hashValue` without a problem, and decode back to an `Int` on the other end. But there doesn't seem to be a way to initialize an enum from its `hashValue`, so I can't turn it back into a `Direction`.

How can I encode and decode a valueless enum?

Comment: So you can't change the Enum to add a raw value. But can you do other changes to the Enum?

Comment: @Sweeper I was hoping for a way to do it without changing the enum. I am curious though, what changes (other than adding a rawValue) would help?

Comment: I was thinking about adding an initialiser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding a raw value to the enum here is the solution with the least code and is the most maintainable. So if you *can* modify the enum, add a raw value.

Now let's assume you can't modify the enum. You still can do this in a few ways.

The first one, which I think is quite ugly, is to add an `extension` of the enum and add a static method like this:

```
static func direction(from rawValue: String) -> Direction {
    switch rawValue {
        case: "north": return .north
        case: "south": return .south
        default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

To convert `Direction` to a codeable value, use `String(describing:)` to convert the enum to a string. To convert a string back to an enum, just use the method above.

The second one, slightly better, but still not as good as just adding a raw value.

You use a dictionary:

```
let enumValueDict: [String: Direction] = [
    "north": .north, "south": .south
]
```

To convert `Direction` to a codeable value, use `String(describing:)` to convert the enum to a string. To convert a string back to an enum, just access the dictionary.

Comment: @arionik Oops! Corrected

Answer (score 5):

New in Swift 4, an enum *is* encodable. However, it must have a raw value. You can easily do with no additional code, however:

```
enum Direction : String, Codable {
    case north
    case south
}
```

To make your Codable enum work with an NSCoding class MyClass, implement your `init(coder:)` and `encode(with:)` like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var direction: Direction!
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        direction = (aDecoder as! NSKeyedUnarchiver).decodeDecodable(Direction.self, forKey: "direction")
    }
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        try? (aCoder as! NSKeyedArchiver).encodeEncodable(direction, forKey: "direction")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define some keys and store them instead.

```
fileprivate let kDirectionKeyNorth = 1
fileprivate let kDirectionKeySouth = 2

// ...

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let key = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "direction")
    switch key {
        case kDirectionKeyNorth:
    // ...
    }
}

// and vise versa
```

It's a bit tricky way. You should always look after the library with `Direction` is part of. And add keys for new directions.

Comment: So if I understand this right, you're assigning a known value to each case of the enum and encoding that, then manually creating a new enum from the decoded value?

Comment: @Robert right! And since `switch` statement must be exhaustive you'll get an issue while compiling if a new `Direction` case will appear.

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5, if your enum `Direction` can have raw values, you can use `Codable` (`Decodable` and `Encodable` protocols) as an alternative to `NSCoding`:

```
enum Direction: String, Codable {
    case north, south
}

final class MyClass: Codable {

    let direction: Direction

    init(direction: Direction) {
        self.direction = direction
    }

}
```

---

Usage:

```
import Foundation

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let myClass = MyClass(direction: .north)

if let data = try? encoder.encode(myClass),
    let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)
}

/*
 prints:
 {"direction":"north"}
 */
```

```
import Foundation

let jsonString = """
{
  "direction" : "south"
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let myClassInstance = try! decoder.decode(MyClass.self, from: jsonData)
dump(myClassInstance)

/*
 prints:
 ▿ __lldb_expr_319.MyClass #0
   - direction: __lldb_expr_319.Direction.south
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make the enum conform to `Codable`. This could be through whichever mechanism you want (e.g. use a raw value such as Int or String, or implement the methods).

So lets assume we have the following:

```
enum Direction { case north, south, east, west }

extension Direction: Codable {
    // etc etc - make it conform
}

final class MyClass: NSObject {
    var direction: Direction!
}
```

In the required methods for `NSCoding`, you can then do the following:

```
extension MyClass: NSCoding {

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let keyedCoder = aCoder as? NSKeyedArchiver else {
            fatalError("Must use Keyed Coding")
        }
        try! keyedCoder.encodeEncodable(direction, forKey: "direction")
    }

    convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        guard let keyedDecoder = aDecoder as? NSKeyedUnarchiver else { 
            fatalError("Must use Keyed Coding") 
        }
        direction = keyedDecoder.decodeDecodable(Direction.self, forKey: "direction") ?? .north
    }
}
```

So, this works, because `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` are aware of `Codable`, but `NSCoder` is not. However, given that `NSArchiver` and `NSUnarchiver` are now deprecated, and essentially, *non-keyed archiving* is strongly discouraged, so for your project, it is safe to use `fatalError()` in this manner - assuming that you test your code.