# Cannot use NSKeyedArchiver to save my model

Tags: ios, swift, enums, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I am getting model from Api and it looks like this:

```
class Device : NSObject, Codable, NSCoding{
    var deviceId : Int?
    var driver : String?
    var address : String?
    var type : DeviceTypes? // Enum type

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.deviceId, forKey: "deviceId")
        coder.encode(self.driver, forKey: "driver")
        coder.encode(self.address, forKey: "address")
        coder.encode(self.type, forKey: CodingKeys.type.rawValue)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()

        self.deviceId = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "deviceId")
        self.driver = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "driver") as? String
        self.address = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "address") as? String
        self.type = coder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.type.rawValue) as? DeviceTypes
    }

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey{
        case deviceId, address, type, deviceType
    }
}
```

Then I am adding some elements to array and it works but when I am trying to archive it with NSKeyedArchiver it throws an Exception :

**[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

**DeviceTypes**

```
enum DeviceTypes : Int, Codable{
    case SYSTEM
    case CE
    case CZ
    case ST
    case KA
    case CR
    case EX
    case DR
    case KL
    case WE
    case WY
    case WL
    case TR
    case LI
    case BR = 30
    case DC = 32
}
```

Comment: What is subType? . Doesn’t seem to exist in class yet is a coding key. Also show code for DeviceType

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I encode enum using NSCoder in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift)

Comment: @WarrenBurton I forgot to remove it because my model contains more properties but I showed only a few. I added DeviceTypes code also as You asked.

Comment: Quick question why use NSCoding & NSKeyedArchiver if it's codable? It already have a serializing way.

Comment: @Larme I need to save my model to file and load it. I have no clue how to achieve it with Codable

Comment: Why did you use Codable? For JSON? Look for `JSONEncoder()` then.

Comment: Because Im downloading it from Api, then I want to save it to file. I can't save it as JSON, because it contains ARWorldMap object too

Comment: "Because Im downloading it from Api, then I want to save it to file. I can't save it as JSON, because it contains ARWorldMap object too " Why not save the data you downloaded directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `NSCoding` is only available for class types. Any attempt to conform `DeviceTypes` to `NSCoding` will result in an error

```
enum DeviceTypes : Int, Codable, NSCoding {
```

> Non-class type 'DeviceTypes' cannot conform to class protocol 'NSCoding'

One solution is to convert back and forth from the `enum` type in your `NSCoding` methods.

Note that `NSCoding` is soft deprecated for `NSSecureCoding` so you should use that conformance to avoid future support issues.

```
class Device : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {

    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

    var deviceId : Int?
    var driver : String?
    var address : String?
    var type : DeviceTypes? // Enum type

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.deviceId, forKey: "deviceId")
        coder.encode(self.driver, forKey: "driver")
        coder.encode(self.address, forKey: "address")

        coder.encode(self.type?.rawValue, forKey: "type")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()

        self.deviceId = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "deviceId")
        self.driver = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "driver") as? String
        self.address = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "address") as? String

        let rawtype = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "type")
        self.type = DeviceTypes(rawValue: rawtype)
    }

}
```

You haven't supplied all the code in your `Device` class as your post fragment doesn't compile with `Codable` conformance so I can't guess at what your system really requires in terms of JSON support.