# Swift NSCoding how to decode custom object

Tags: swift, nscoding, nscoder

I've a dictionary ("equippedItems") of custom objects that I'd like to encode and decode.

```
var equippedItems = [ItemType : ItemEntity]()
```

I've tried to encode it as following:

```
override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(equippedItems, forKey: "Equiptments")
}
```

but it causes the app to crash. Therefore I tried to use the following code to encode it and app no longer crashes. Is that the right way?

```
override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        let eq = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: equippedItems, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        aCoder.encode(eq, forKey: "Equiptments")
}
```

However, now I'm having trouble decoding the object in the following function:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    equippedItems = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Equiptments") as! [ItemType: ItemEntity]
}
```

The app crashes with an error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Although I don't get an error from the encoding lines, I'm still not sure if it was the correct way to encode it.

Can someone please show me how I encode and decode it properly?

Comment: Do both `ItemType` and `ItemEntity` conform to `NSCoding`?

Comment: `eq` is `Data`. You have to decode `Data` and **unarchive** the custom type.

Comment: @Vadian, can you please show me the code on how to unarchive Data from within required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

Comment: I don't know what `ItemType` and `ItemEntity` contains. Please read https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-nskeyedunarchiver-unarchiveobject

Comment: @Vadian, Thanks for the link. I did read through it, however it still does not tell me how I can decode the Data  from within required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder). I could not find anything from NSKeyedUnarchiver that would allow me to retrieve my encoded Data from a key("Equiptments"). The only way I could come up with was to do: let data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Equiptments"), then  equippedItems = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as! Data) as! [ItemType: ItemEntity]. but it crashes the app.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use NSCoding you have to make every object in your object graph conform to NSCoding.  Where is your NSCoding conformance for `ItemType` and  `ItemEntity`?

Comment: ItemType is an enum of Int and ItemEntity is a subclass of GKEntity. They should both conform to NSCoding as I have no trouble encode Set<ItemEntity>, but not a dictionary made of [ItemType: ItemEntity].

Comment: Swift types like Swift enums do not conform to NSCoding. You need to provide NSCoding conformance. The good news is that it's really easy for Int enums.

Comment: can you please show me how?

Comment: Try this link, for example (Search term "NSCoding Swift Enum" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, it does not show how to encode dictionary at all. converting ItemType to it's rawValue doesn't help.